# Assign values to pointers inside structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having troubles assigning values to pointers inside structs, I have this struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int numCliente;
    tCadena nombre;
    char *iva;
    int *tiposerv;
    float *monto;
}tCliente;
```

and I have a function :

```
tCliente cargarUno(int numC){   

    tCliente reg;

    char letra;
    int serv;
    float mon;

    reg.numCliente=numC;

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese Nombre del cliente:");
    leeCad(reg.nombre,20);

    printf("\nIngrese condicion de IVA(M-Monotributista,R-Responsable Inscripto,E- IVA Exento):");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&letra); 
    &reg->iva = &letra; 
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nIngrese tipo de servicio(1 2 3):" );  
    scanf("%d",&serv);
    &reg->tiposerv = &serv;


    printf("\nIngrese monto a cobrar:");
    scanf("%f",&mon);
    &reg->monto= &mon;

    return reg;
}
```

When I try to show the struct, the pointers are not showing the values I put.

```
void mostrarUno(tCliente c){

    printf("Numero del cliente:%d",c.numCliente);

    printf("\n Nombre del cliente:%s",c.nombre);    

    printf("\n Condicion IVA:%c",*c.iva);
    printf("\n Tipo de servicio:%d",*c.tiposerv);

    printf("\n Monto a Cobrar:%f",*c.monto);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior* in the standard, so you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning pointers to local variables to the fields of the struct. For example, `&reg->tiposerv = &serv;` makes the field `tiposerv` point to `serv`, which is a local variable in the function.

When the function returns to `main`, those local variables are destroyed. This is why you are not getting their values.

One possible solution is to dynamically allocate the pointer fields using `malloc`. For example:

```
reg.tiposerv = malloc(sizeof(int));
*(reg.tiposerv) = serv;
```

Comment: I was thinking on that, so how can i assing values?

Comment: 1) "For example, `&reg->tiposerv = &serv;` makes the field `tiposerv` point to `serv`" this is wrong. The statement will emit compile error. 2) `new` isn't supported in (at least, standard) C.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `&reg->iva = &letra;`, `&reg->tiposerv = &serv;` and `&reg->monto= &mon;` will emit compile error because `->` operator is evaluated before `&` operator and `reg` is not a pointer.
You should write like `(&reg)->iva` or more simply `reg.iva`.

Then, stop assigning pointers to non-static local variables. They will vanish on exiting their scope (exiting the function `cargarUno()` in this case) and dereferencing the pointers after that will invoke *undefined behavior*.
One way to fix is to allocate some memory dynamically like these:

```
char *letra = malloc(sizeof(char));
int *serv = malloc(sizeof(int));
float *mon = malloc(sizeof(float));
/* check if the allocations are successful here */

/* ... */

scanf("%c",letra); 
reg.iva = letra;

/* correct lefthand operand of = as descrived above
 * and remove & on the left of serv and mon like this */
```

If you will only assign pointers to single data and you won't deal with arrays, I don't think using pointers like this is good. Why not simply store data directly like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int numCliente;
    tCadena nombre;
    char iva;
    int tiposerv;
    float monto;
}tCliente;

/* ... */

scanf("%c",&reg.iva);

/* ... */

scanf("%d",&reg.tiposerv);

/* ... */

scanf("%f",&reg.monto);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate the memory space for the `tCliente reg;`.
You should allocate the mem space first before you assign the values for the elements of in the structure.

I modified your function `cargarUno()` as followed:

```
void cargarUno(tCliente *reg, int numC){   

//tCliente reg;

...
reg->numCliente=numC;

...
leeCad(reg->nombre,20);

...
reg->iva = &letra; 

...
reg->tiposerv = &serv;

...
reg->monto= &mon;

//return reg;
}
```

And try to allocate the memory space for the tCliente *reg,

```
int i=X; // assign the int you desire
tCliente *reg=malloc(sizeof(tCliente));
cargarUno(reg,i);
```

Comment: C has been able to return whole structures since the early 1980s; the code in the question did not have problems with allocating `reg`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Yes, you're right. There's no need to allocate mem for the structure in this question.